# nestjs typeorm can't resolve DataSource as dependency

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I use TypeORM version 0.3.12 and @nestjs/typeorm version 9.0.1.

I have four NestJS repositories:

1. entity(npm repo)
2. base-service(npm repo)
3. a-service
4. b-service

entity and base-service are npm-published repositories. The entity repository is a collection of simple entities, while the base-service repository contains common modules and services used in the a-service and b-service repositories. The a-service and b-service repositories use the modules and services in the base-service repository.

Here are the code snippets:

1. entity

user.entity

```js
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  idx: number;

  @Column('varchar', { length: 100 })
  id: string;
}
```

2. base-service

base-user.module.ts

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { BaseUserRepository } from './base-user.repository';
import { User } from 'entity';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User])],
  providers: [BaseUserRepository],
  exports: [],
})
export class BaseUserModule {}
```

base-user.repository.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { User } from 'entity'

@Injectable()
export class BaseUserRepository {
  constructor(@InjectRepository(User) private readonly repository: Repository<User>) {}
}
```

3. a-service

app.module.ts

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { MysqlConfigService } from './app/mysql/mysql-config.service';
import { BaseUserModule } from 'base-service';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({ useClass: MysqlConfigService }),
    BaseUserModule,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

When running the a-service, I received the following error:

```
Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserRepository (?). Please make sure that the argument DataSource at index [0] is available in the TypeOrmModule context.
```

I think that the TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User]) in the base-service repository, which was installed via npm, cannot find the context. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: How are you connecting your npm repos in this local context? I'm gonna bet that there's two `@nestjs/typeorm` /`@nestjs/common`/`@nestjs/core` instances, unintentionally, that are messing up the `instanceof` check(s)

Comment: @JayMcDoniel 'base-service' and 'entity' is just example. It is private npm repository

Comment: Okay, but are you locally linking, are you installing, are you using the `file:` protocol in npm, how are you using the repos?

Comment: publish and install the repo.

Comment: Okay. In the repos do you use `peerDependencies` for any `@nestjs/` deps?